# Drawable setColorFilter not work on Nexus 7

Tags: android, colors, drawable, nexus-7, colorfilter

I want to change color of android design drawable to blue. This is piece of my code in application class onCreate method:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rating_not_important);
drawable.setColorFilter(0xff1565c0, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rating_important);
drawable.setColorFilter(0xff1565c0, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

It works on emulator (API 4.0.3) and a Xperia P mobile device (API 4.1.2), but not work on Nexus 7 tablet. Star drawable has its default white color with no change.I have tested Mode.MULTIPLY and Mode.LIGHTEN and no success. Please help!

Comment: what kind of Drawables are they?  BitmapDrawable,  ShapeDawable etc?

Comment: they are .png images (holo dark ActionBarIcons from Android Design Icons 2013)

Comment: so try the simple way to test it: d = new BitmapDrawable(....); d.setColorFilter(...); view.setBackground(d)

Comment: BitmapDrawable also works on other devices but not in Nexus.The point is when I put ChangeColor codes right before setImageResource(..) (in the listView adapter getView method), then it works on all devices but when it is in the Application extended class then it works on all devices but Nexus. I want to use setColorFilter only once and use it in listview adapter many times. Is it possible?

Comment: " ChangeColor codes  " what codes?  "Application extended class" what do you mean?  does BitmapDraeable.setColorFilter work when you run my snippet from my previous comment?

Comment: Oh sorry for bad expressions! ChangeColor codes are exactly my code block in question. Application extended class is like this : public class G extends Application{...}

Comment: ok what custom Application class has to do with Drawable.setColorFilter ? does BitmapDrawable.setColorFilter work correctly?

Comment: BitmapDrawable works but exactly like simple drawable (only when I write it before drwable.setColorFilter(..)) I want to setColorfilter in Application class and use it in adapter getview method